# sharedpreferences null method check

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I have seven different activities and i call all data in final activity to calculate it, in all activities  i placed a button with failsafe that if edit text is empty no next button is nonclickable.

Problem arises now if a user click directly the result page my application crashes, due to no data in sharedpreferences to calculate,

I want to have some method or code to check if DOUBLE of my sharedpreferences or entire file is empty user should get a toast message 'Fill the values first' and calculation page does not open. this way my app will remain alive.

Am I thinking in right direction?

---

Some example code:

please note seeresults is a button which is clicked to open page having calculation results (sharedpreferences values are accessed).

variable 'v' is a double

I have entered following code but its again having problems (if statement cannot be compared with double), can any one help me out

```
seeresults.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                abcPref = this.getSharedPreferences(FILE1, 0);
                Boolean bCheck = abcPref.getBoolean("v", false);

                if (v == -1) { Toast message = Toast.makeText(Timesaving.this, "No Data or Parameteres Was Entered in forms", 3000);
                message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL , 0, 0);
                message.show();
                finish();} 
                else{
                Intent openresult = new Intent("com.ideals.ideal.RESMAIN");
                startActivity(openresult);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It sounds like you probably are in the right direction but it would be easier to help if you provide code. Also, why even let them go to the results page if there is no data to calculate?

Comment: I think the direction is fine.
What do you mean by "DOUBLE of my sharedpreferences"?

Comment: i have huge data entry in 8 pages 40 variables, and hoem page with button to result page. Like i said i want result page to non responsive if sharedpreferences are empty. what i can do is call last variables to be entered in result page first and check them in if else statement, for that i need to know how to check a double value if its null..

Comment: @RaphMclee double is int float type variable..

Comment: does it called nullpoint exception???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
Boolean bCheck = sPrefs.getBoolean("ButtonReceiverState", false);
```

When you are trying to retrieve the values from the sharedPreferences the call provides a fail-safe exactly for the possible nullpointer; you can set a default-value if there is no value found for a key.

In my case here, the boolean is set to `false` if there is no value to retrieve. This works for all different datatypes aswell.

Comment: thanks bofredo, how to can you club it with toast to a user??

Comment: a good idea would be to set the default-value to some unique number that your editText cant have (maybe -1). Then in your final activity you can build in checks that are looking for the "-1" and handle it properly.  Feel free to accept answer if it solves your issue :-)

Comment: if (value == -1) { Toast.makeText(context, "my Text here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

Comment: please see my update and check if its in line you suggested, i want my activity to not start finish(); statement is optional..

Answer (score 0):

A double will never be null. Java initializes it to 0 automatically. What you could do is set the default value for the preference where you use the double to `Double.NaN` and check against that.

Or you simple could define reasonable default values which will work for your calculations and which the user could change at will.